# want to navigate to detail page

Tags: apex, controller, component, lightning-card

Hi yal i am New on salesforce want to navigate to a contact Detail page through Button.How to pass parameter ? How can i do please help.

**Apex Class**:-

```
public class ShowContactInCard {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<contact> getConList(){
        List <contact> ConList =[select Id,LastName,phone,Department,Description,LeadSource,Email,Title from Contact where LeadSource= 'web'];
        Return ConList;
    }
}
```

**Component :-**

```
<aura:component controller="ShowContactInCard" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:Attribute name ="ContactList" type ="Contact[]"/>
  
    <aura:Attribute name ="recordId" type ="String"/> 
    
   
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Show Contacts"  title="action" onclick="{!c.CallApexMethod}" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Close" title="action" onclick="{!c.Close}" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    <!--after completing Controller-->
    <aura:iteration items = "{!v.ContactList}" var ="con" >
       
       
        
        <!--CARD BELOW-->
     <lightning:card  title="{!con.LastName}" iconName="standard:contact">
         
          <!--BUTTON BELOW-->
         <div class="slds-size_2-of-1">
         <lightning:button variant="brand-outline" label="View Detail" name="{!con.Id}" title="action" onclick="{!c.Detail}" />
         </div>
  
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">             
            {!con.Phone}<br/>
            {!con.Department}<br/>
            {!con.Description}<br/>
            {!con.LeadSource}        
        </p>
         <aura:set attribute ="footer">
             {!con.Email}<br/>
             {!con.Title}
        </aura:set> 
         
    </lightning:card>    
    </aura:iteration> 
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:-**

```
({
    CallApexMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
        //1. call Apex Class Method..(which we called inside component with the help of controller)    
var action = component.get("c.getConList");
        
        //2.Pass the parameter if it is Reqired on Apex method.
        var accIdVar = component.get('v.recordId');
        action.setParams({
            accId : accIdVar
        });
        
        //place the request to the queue
        $A.enqueueAction(action,false);
        
        
        // receive the result with the help of setcallBack
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            //we can read state of apex class (success,errror,incomplete)
            var state = response.getState();
              //if success
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
               var responseValue = response.getReturnValue();
                 //pass the result to component
                 component.set('v.ContactList',responseValue);
            }
             //if incomplete
              //if(state === "INCOMPLETE"){}
              
             /*if error
              else if(state === "ERROR"){
                  console.log('failed');
              }*/
            
        });        
    },
    
    //Close Button..
      Close : function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": component.get('v.recordId'),
      
    });
    navEvt.fire();
},
    
   Detail: function (component, event, helper) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get('v.recordId'),
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    }  
    
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recordId which you are setting as params in Detail method is ID of record from which you are invoking your lightning component not the contact Id to which you want to navigate.You need to pass contact Id.You can try below code

**Cmp change**

Replace

```
 <lightning:button variant="brand-outline" label="View Detail" name="{!con.Id}" title="action" onclick="{!c.Detail}" />
```

with

```
 <button type="button" onclick="{!c.Detail}" id="{!con.Id}" >View Details</button>
```

**Controller change**

```
 Detail: function (component, event, helper) {
   
    var idx = event.target.id;
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": idx
        
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```